# QStandardItem global position

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt version is 5.5.1 (Linux) and for some reason I can't upgrade it.

I have QTableView (inherits from QWidget), and this QTableView have model QStandardItemModel with some QStandardItem. Question is: How to obtain QStandarditem global coordination in this situation?

ui file

```
QWidget *MY_QWidget;
MY_QTableView *MY_QTableView;
MY_QWidget = new QWidget();
MY_QTableView = new QTableView(MY_QWidget);
```

h file

```
QStandardItemModel * MY_QStandardItemModel;
```

cpp file

```
MY_QStandardItemModel = new QStandardItemModel();
ui->MY_QTableView->setModel(MY_QStandardItemModel);

QStandardItem *MY_QStandardItem;
MY_QStandardItem  = new QStandardItem(tr("some text"));
MY_QStandardItemModel->setItem(0,0,MY_QStandardItem);// <- Global position of this item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting local position of `QStandardItem` you can use [QAbstractItemView::visualRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qabstractitemview.html#visualRect):

```
QModelIndex index = MY_QStandardItemModel->indexFromItem(MY_QStandardItem);
QRect rect = MY_QTableView->visualRect(index);
Qpoint localPoint = rect.topLeft(); // <- the local position
```

And for getting global position you can use [QWidget::mapToGlobal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal):

```
Qpoint globalPosition MY_QTableView->mapToGlobal(localPoint); // <- the global position
```